# Prestashop add css to a module

Tags: php, css, module, prestashop

I am creating a module in prestashop 1.4, say `blocktest`

modules/blocktest/blocktest.php:

```
...

public function hookLeftColumn($params)
{
    global $smarty;
    $smarty->assign(array(
        'test' => 'test'
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blocktest.tpl');
}

public function hookHeader()
{
    Tools::addCSS($this->_path.'blocktest.css', 'all');
}
```

modules/blocktest/blocktest.css:

```
* { background-color: red; }
```

---

#### Problem:

My css is not included.

---

#### What i tried:

In `admin > preferences > performances > smarty`, i have set cache to `no`, and force compile to `yes`. In `admin > preferences > performances > smarty`, cache is set to `no`.

Existing modules uses the same css inclusion : `Tools::addCSS($this->_path.'blocktest.css', 'all');`, but the css file is in `<themeName>/css/modules/<moduleName>/<moduleName>.css`. Which is wierd, because $this->_path points to the module folder : `modules/<moduleName>/`.

But anyway, I tried to put my css file in  `<themeName>/css/modules/blocktest/blocktest.css`, that doesn't work. Maybe i am missing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you remember about registering a hook for the header during module's installation?

```
function install() {
    if (!parent::install())
        return false;
    if (!$this->registerHook('header'))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Without it you will have to use "transplant module" function from Admin > Modules > Positions, to do this. Always check with tools like Firebug to verify whether your files are there.

Also, I think there is something missing, can you supply us with the **full** code of your module? Please, provide us with a Prestashop version that you use as well.

Comment: Didn't think about registering all the hooks i used, thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

Other solution:

```
$this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'style.css', 'all'); 
$this->context->controller->addJs(($this->_path).'script.js', 'all');
```

Greetings,

source info:

http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/235476-solucionadoerror-en-mi-1ra-web-warning-function-addcss-is-deprecated-in/

Answer (score 1):

> Which is wierd, because $this->_path points to the module folder :
>   modules//

yes it is (weird), but... in the addCSS function, it is overriden with (module) themes css folder

```
public static function addCSS($css_uri, $css_media_type = 'all')
{
  global $css_files;
   ...
  $css_uri = str_replace(__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/', __PS_BASE_URI__.'themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/css/modules/', $css_uri, $different);
   ...
}
```